# How to use ngx-guided-tour in parent-child component relation

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am in situation where we have to use [ngx-guided-tour](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-guided-tour?activeTab=readme) library. Our project layout is like we have Parent component at left which has list of tiles on click of tile we are showing details of that tile in right component.
Problem: As you read we have parent child component relation. In [ngx-guided-tour](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-guided-tour?activeTab=readme) they have shown in single component only but how can I achieve that in my case that is little challenging for me. Any idea how should I approach?